# Sorting of priority_queue elements that are pointer type

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say we have a priority_queue that holds a bunch of ListNode objects declared as below:

```
class ListNode {
  int val;
  ListNode *next;
public:
  explicit ListNode(int v) : val(v), next(NULL) {}
  inline bool operator<(const ListNode& rhs) const {
    return val < rhs.val;
  }
};

std::priority_queue<ListNode> pq;
```

By overriding operator< method or providing a sorting functor we can have the priority_queue hold the ListNode objects in val's ascending order.

My question is if the priority_queue holds the pointers to ListNode class instead can I have the pointers sorted so that the val's pointed are in ascending order. How do I do that?

```
std::priority_queue<ListNode *> pq1;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try [this predicate template](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11774863/596781).

Comment: @KerrekSB,   : ptr_compare functor also serves my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) accepts as third template parameter a comparison functor that it has to use to perform the comparisons.

Just write your own that dereferences the items before comparing them:

```
template<typename T>
struct PtrLess
{
    bool operator()(const T* left, const T* right)
    {
        return *left < *right;
    }
};


std::priority_queue<ListNode *, std::vector< ListNode * >, PtrLess< ListNode > > pq1;
```

Comment: Agh... you were a split second earlier :)

Comment: @CygnusX1: happens all the time :) +1 to your answer too.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: if the compare function is used, is the second parameter std::vector< ListNode * > optional?

Comment: @itnovice: unfortunately, no, if you want to specify a custom third parameter you cannot use the default for the second parameter (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215838/c-default-values-for-template-arguments-other-than-the-last-ones)).

Answer (score 3):

A pointer to `ListNode` is like an everyday pointer. You cannot overload an operator between two pointers.

However, you can override the comparison operator for the purpose of the `priority_queue`. It would go something like this:

```
struct ListNodePtrLess {
    bool operator()(const ListNode* a, const ListNode* b) {
        return a->val < b->val;
    }
};

typedef std::priority_queue<ListNode*, std::vector<ListNode*>, ListNodePtrLess> MyPriorityQueue;
```

(also: you will need to make `ListNodePtrLess` a friend of `ListNode`, or let it access the `val` field in some different way)